# If MFA enabled in AWS cognito, do I need to create js on client side to call cognitoUser.authenticateUser() because of the promt for code?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using reactjs and node for server side.

As you can see in the "mfa required" part of the code below, if this is all on node, then I can't really do "prompt" the user for the code, I have to pass this back to the front end.

**Tried solution:** If I do pass the MFA required to front end and get the users input then send it back to node to call "respondToAuth" I am getting two MFA codes in my SMS message.

**Have I tried other solutions?**
I am hesitant to use amplify because everything is on the front end, I would ideally like to do my authentication on the back end (thus node).
Another option I am leaning towards is just using initiateAuth api instead of "cognitoUser.AuthenticateUser". This way I can get the challenge response and pass it on in sequence. But as per my initial question, I am wondering if I can implement the below code and be able to route users to input MFA code (without duplicating MFA sms message)

```js
AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.Region
});
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

const poolData = { //--Moved to env variables
  UserPoolId: process.env.UserPoolId, // your user pool id here
  ClientId: process.env.ClientId // your app client id here
};
const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);


router.post('/api/authenticateuser', (req, res) => {
  const val = req.body;
  var userData = {
    Username: val.value.user, // your username here
    Pool: userPool
  };
  var authenticationData = {
    Username: val.value.user, // your username here
    Password: val.value.pass, // your password here
  };
  const authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
  const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function(result) {
      console.log('You are now logged in.');
      console.log(result);
      const accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

      const idToken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
      res.json({
        accessToken,
        idToken
      });
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
      res.json(err);
    },
    mfaRequired: function(codeDeliveryDetails) {
      // console.log("mfa enabled");

      // var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code' ,'');
      // cognitoUser.sendMFACode(verificationCode, this);

      // res.json({ MFA:codeDeliveryDetails})
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: I'm also looking for similar approach i.e, mfa authentication in nodejs by collecting verificationCode from frontend, so have you found any solution?

Comment: any updates on this? @rio